# Calculating the center of a rotated 2D rectangle given it's bottom left point, angle of rotation and dimensions

Tags: trigonometry

I have a rectangle that can be rotated around its center point.
I would like to know what the coordinates of the center are, but I'm not sure how to get that with the information available to me.
I have the length and height of the rectangle and the angle of rotation. In addition, I have the coordinates of the corner that was initially the bottom left one. Like x<sub>a</sub>,y<sub>a</sub> in [this image (where the rotation angle is 0)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzdES.png)

My best suggestion for a solution right now is to find the remaining 3 corners and then calculating the center from that, but I hope someone can help me find a more elegant way.

Comment: If you know $(x_a,y_a)$ and the length and height of the rectangle, say $l$ and $h$, then the center is simply at $(x_a+\tfrac l2,y_a+\frac{h}{2})$. Am I missing something?

Comment: If the angle is 0 that works, but what if it's rotated?